# How to add route to Buffalo router

Tags: routing, buffalo-router

I'm trying to understand what I can make use with this feature on my Buffalo WHR-HP-GN router.  Using the User Friendly Firmware, I've clicked on the Internet / LAN -> Route menu, and am presented with the following:
**Add Routing**
Destination Address:  
Gateway:              
Metric:

However, when I attempted to add the following:
Destination Address:  192.168.60.4
Gateway:              192.168.20.22
Metric:               15 (This is the default)

I'm given the following:
ERROR: Destination Address
description: IP Address is not valid as network address

The reason I entered the above is because I have the following setup:

```
Internet -> Buffalo Router -> 192.168.20.1/24  
                           -> Another Router (192.168.20.22) -> 192.168.60.1/24  
                                                             -> Device (192.168.60.4)
```

Comment: If you want to add route to single host, you should choose Subnet Mask 255.255.255.255

Comment: @dusan.bajic  Thanks!  That was it!  The Subnet Mask is defaluted to 255.255.255.0 so it didn't work.  In fact I am now able to ping from within my 192.168.20.1/24 network to the Device at 192.168.60.4.  However, what I don't understand is why is this the case.  If I goto http://www.subnet-calculator.com/, the combination of [192.168.60.1 & 255.255.255.0] or [192.168.60.4 & 255.255.255.0] results in the same network.  I want to add the whole 192.168.60.1/24 network.  HOw can I do this?

Comment: The very first address in subnet is used as "network address", so if you want to add 192.168.60.x/24, you need to enter [192.168.60.0 & 255.255.255.0]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add route to single host, you should choose Destination Address  192.168.60.4 and Subnet Mask 255.255.255.255

If you want to add the whole 192.168.60.X/24 network, use the very first address in subnet as "network address", so the right combination is [192.168.60.0 & 255.255.255.0]

Comment: Thanks.  Just experimented for this and it worked.  Just tried to come back to let you know but guess you beat me to it.  Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed 2 issues.  1) If I connect my PC to the 192.168.20.0/24 network, I can not ping the 192.168.60.4 device (sitting behind the second router at 192.168.20.22) until I ping the second router first.  As soon as I have pinged the second router at 192.168.20.22, I can ping the device at 192.168.60.4.  Any idea why this is the case?  2) For some reason I can access the web page hosted on 192.168.60.4 from my iPhone but not from my PC.  Both are connected to the 192.168.20.0/24 network in the same way.  How can this be?

Comment: is that a windows pc?

Comment: Yes it's a Windows 7 PC.

Comment: Any idea?  Curious why you asked if it's a Windows.

Comment: try adding this route to windows pc (from CMD):  ROUTE ADD 192.168.60.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.20.22 and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks.  I understand why you suggested this.  However, the static route I added to the Buffalo router should have enabled this anyway, isn't it?  I don't quite understand why it's not doing it and it's only happening to my PC too while the iPhone is fine!

Comment: I know you added it to Buffalo, but can you try and add it to windows machine also (for testing purposes)?

Comment: Thanks and sorry I haven't tried it yet.  I tried the same thing with a different Windows 7 machine and it works without having to do anything.

Comment: I have finally managed to do the route add and I can now a) access the device via a browser, b) map the device as a drive, c) access it via windows Explorer.  However, I'm still unable to get Windows to show it under Windows Explorer -> Network.

Comment: Perhaps you should post that in new question with proper title (that would help getting the right answer)

Comment: Thanks.  Think the answer was posted by MariusMatutiae on http://superuser.com/questions/668698/windows-7-can-ping-but-cant-see-device-on-other-subnet.  However this also highlights how faulty the Buffalo implementation is.