# Windows 7 can ping but can't see device on other subnet

Tags: windows-7, subnet

I have 2 Windows 7 on 2 different subnets but 1 of them is unable to reach a NAS.  The topology is as follow.  Any idea why this is the case?  Is there some Windows settings I need to apply?

Subnet 1
- PC 1
- NAS

Subnet 2
- PC 2

PC 1 is able to do the following:
- Load the admin page on the browser.
- Show the NAS under Windows Explorer -> Network.
- Access the NAS when typed in \\ in Windows Explorer.

PC 2 is unable to do any of the above 3.  It can however ping the NAS and get a response.

Comment: Can you please post the routing table of pc 2?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thanks for the pointer.  I didn't see the route and added it using "route add" and I can now a) access the device via a browser, b) map the device as a drive, c) access it via windows Explorer. However, I'm still unable to get Windows to show it under Windows Explorer -> Network.  Any idea a) why I need to do a "route add", and b) why I can't still see the device under Windows Explorer -> Network?

Comment: The pcs are on different subnets. Network Manager only knows how to explore network to which it is connected, defined by the (presumably restrictive) mask that the DHCP provides. Why should it know what happens beyond the pillars of Hercules? To connect the two subnets permanently, apart from making the new route permanent with the -p option, you may wish to explore the possibility of making your network mask less restrictive, something like 255.255.0.0. But you have to do that on what provides DHCP service, modem or router.